# Gradle force copy task to be executed

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have the following task to copy a file:

```
task copyFiles(type: Copy) {
    def folder = rootProject.file('/a/b/c')
    println folder.absolutePath
    println folder.exists()
    from(folder) {
        include '*.*'
    }
    into(rootProject.file('/c/b'))
}
```

I am trying to execute this task as a standalone copy task, so without any binding to the compiling of the project etc.

The problem is that the task is never executed (NO-SOURCE) despite the folder existing:

```
    C:\...\a\b\b
true
:projectName:copyFiles NO-SOURCE
```

Comment: One note, one qeustion. _Note:_ do not start your paths with a slash. If you ever come to the point where you run the build on *nix, you are f***** up, because there paths starting with a slash are absolute paths, not relative paths. This will only and exclusively work on Windows and OS/2. _Question:_ you check that the folder exists, but are you sure there are files with a dot in their name in there? Because that is what you filter on.

Answer (score 2):

`NO-SOURCE` means that the copy task did not find any files to copy based on your configuration.

If `/a/b/c` are directories as sub-directories in relation to your `build.gradle` project file then this should work provided that the `/c` folder contains any files that follow the `*.*` pattern for names.

https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy.html